# RDP Azure VM not working due to RDS license issue

Tags: windows, azure, server, azure-virtual-machine

I'm getting the error below.

Error: "The remote session was disconnected because there was no terminal server license server available to provide a license"

[image]

Seems to be an issue with the RDS. How do I connect to the VM to reset the grace period or buy the license?

A prompt respose would really be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Launch the RDP connection as console.

```
mstsc /admin
```

That should allow you to RDP if the issue is a licence issue.